# Swagger ExpressJS return No operations defined in spec

Tags: express, swagger

Hello I'm trying to use swagger to my express server but return 'No operations defined in spec!' I already watch like 5 different videos but still has no luck how to fix this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Configurations looks correct only some adjustments in definition and options should work, Here are the code you should re-arrange,

You should write yaml double spaced instead of Tab,

```
/**
 * @swagger
 *  /api/v1/friends:
 *   get:
 *     tags:
 *     - "Healthcheck"
 *     summary: summary of your api endpoint.
 *     description: description of your api endpoint.
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: List of topics.
 */
```

Pass swagger options with these configurations do change values based on your application, validate file path if specified accurately, Most values are optional see [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-jsdoc) for more details

```
const swaggerOptions = {
  openapi: '3.0.0',
  swaggerDefinition: {
    info: {
      title: 'Friends API',
      version: '1.0.0',
      description: 'Friends api endpoints',
      servers: ['https://your-api-serverhosturl.com'],
    },
    produces: ['application/json'],
  },
  apis: ['../modules/friends/*.routes.js'],
};

const swaggerDocs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerOptions);
app.use('/api/api-docs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(swaggerDocs));
```

Navigate to `http://yourhost:port/api/api-docs`